# Resize HBox regardless of its content

Tags: java, javafx, responsive

**Situation**
I'm using a BoarderPane where its center is a HBox. The HBox itself contains dynamically created Rectangles.

The empty HBox grows and shrinks like expected when resizing the Stage.

But as soon as the HBox contains Rectangles, the HBox looses the ability to shrink. It can only shrink to the point where its content is still being displayed.

How can I keep the behavior shown in an empty HBox?
How can I make the HBox shrink without considering if the content has enough space or not?
The resizing of the Rectangles will be managed by the programmer with a Listener on the Hboxes width and height Property. The listener works aslong as the size of the hbox is enough to display all of the rectangle

I guess there are two options to solve this: 1. Make HBox ignore Childs (Rectangles) visabilty 2. Make Rectangles auto ajust to its Parent(HBox) size without having to write a Listener yourself

**Reproduce Problem**

1. Setup JavaFX Application
2. Use following code to generate GUI
3. Resize the Window with the mouse and see behavior

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE,null,null)));
        BorderPane.setMargin(hBox,new Insets(20,20,20,20));
        root.setCenter(hBox);

        //Adding child makes HBox not shrink if childs can't be displayed if Stage size is being changed
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(200,200);
        Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(200,200);
        HBox.setMargin(rectangle,new Insets(20,20,20,20));
        HBox.setMargin(rectangle2,new Insets(20,20,20,20));
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(List.of(rectangle,rectangle2));

        VBox left = new VBox();
        left.setBackground(new Background(newBackgroundFill(Color.GREEN,null,null)));
        root.setLeft(left);
        left.setPrefWidth(100);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        primaryStage.setWidth(700);
        primaryStage.setHeight(500);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem can now be reproduced

Comment: `hBox.setMinSize(0,0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `HBox`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html), the minimum width of a `HBox` is computed as:

> left/right insets plus the sum of each child's min width plus spacing between each child

If you want the `HBox` to be able to be sized smaller than that, you should explicitly replace its minimum width (and probably height too):

```
hBox.setMinSize(0, 0);
```

This allows the `HBox` to be made smaller, as can be seen by portions of the margin being visible after resizing:

[image]

[image]

Note that a `BorderPane` will not clip the content by default. Again, referring to the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html):

> BorderPane does not clip its content by default

This is why you see the rectangles being painted over the top of the margin in the screenshot above.

Fixing this is a little trickier. You can create a `Rectangle` to use as the clip for the `HBox`, ensuring the width and height of the clip match the width and height of the `HBox`.

You can do

```
    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
    hBox.setClip(clip);
    clip.widthProperty().bind(hBox.widthProperty());
    clip.heightProperty().bind(hBox.heightProperty());
```

or (probably better):

```
    HBox hBox = new HBox() {
        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
        {
            setClip(clip);
        }
        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            clip.setWidth(getWidth());
            clip.setHeight(getHeight());
            super.layoutChildren();
        }
    };
```

Either of these gives

[image]